# TinyMCE/MCImageManager path problems

Tags: path, tinymce, mcimagemanager

I am having all sorts of weird issues with paths in the tinyMCE.  I'm not sure if it has to do with the MCImageManaI'll try to summarize my setup:

I've got a .NET website.  For now the application root is at http://localhost/APP/

tiny_mce is hosted in ~/tiny_mce, the imagemanager plugin is of course in ~/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager

~/uploads is where I want the images to be uploaded/managed

~/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/web.config contains this key:  `<add key="filesystem.rootpath" value="../../../upload" />`

It also contains     `<add key="preview.urlprefix" value="{proto}://{host}/APP/" />`
to account for the app root being not at the hostname root (seriously, I shouldn't have to hardcode that....but that's another issue)

So far so good -- when I browse from the image dialog in tinyMCE, I get the image browser and it browses the correct folder

The weirdness starts when I select an image.  Here's what gets put in the "Image URL" box on the "Insert/edit image" form:

../APPot/upload/Image.JPG

APPot?  What the hell?  Shouldn't it just be "upload/Image.JPG"?

This was with

```
tinyMCE.init({
//.....
relative_urls: true,
remove_script_host: true,
document_base_url: 'http://localhost/APP/'
});
```

and also

```
mcImageManager.init({
relative_urls: true,
remove_script_host: true,
document_base_url: 'http://localhost/APP/'
});
```

I can't tell if that second one is necessary, or even doing anything

where is "ot" coming from?  I assume its existance is why it can't figure out how to use the document_base_url.

If I reset the url prefix to the original setting:  `<add key="preview.urlprefix" value="{proto}://{host}/" />`, i end up with:

../upload/DSCF0546.JPG

which actually seems a little closer.  No "ot" crammed in there, but it's a directory off.

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

**Example configuration**

- your web `www.example.com` has DocumentRoot `/var/www-data/`
- you upload you images to                    `/var/www/uploads/images`
- you serve your images from vhost `static.example.com` with DocumentRoot `/var/www`

**Corresponding settings**

- set `preview.wwwroot` to `/var/www`
- set `filesystem.rootpath` to `/var/www/uploads/images`
- set `preview.urlprefix` to `http://static.example.com` (or `//static.example.com`)

### Extended explanation

Happily coding when **wild** 'ds' appears!

The issue is with `Moxiecode_ManagerEngine::convertPathToURI` that uses a piece of code `$uri = substr($abs_path, strlen($root));` where `$abs_path` is the "server" path (`/var/www/uploads/images/image.png`) and `$root` is `$root = $this->getSiteRoot();`. By default MCIE tries to "guess" the siteroot url (it guesses wrong `/var/www-data/`). In my case I saved the uploaded the files to different server, where the siteurl was little bit different. So the substr removed completely unrelated part of the `$abs_path`

```
substr('/var/www/uploads/images/image.png', strlen('/var/www-data/')) == 'ds/images/image.png'
```

To fix this, you need to set `preview.wwwroot` config directive. If set, it's returned from getSiteRoot and stripped accordingly.

```
substr('/var/www/uploads/images/image.png', strlen('/var/www/')) == 'uploads/images/image.png'
```

The code of `Moxiecode_ManagerEngine::convertPathToURI` is dumb and should be fixed, but this solution is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since `relative_urls:` is true, `document_based_url` is used to generate the path. Try setting `relative_urls:` to false. Here's some documentation which explains the options:

- [MCImageManager:rootpath](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager%3arootpath)
- [MCImageManager:relative_urls](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager%3arelative_urls)
- [MCImageManager:document_base_url](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/MCImageManager%3adocument_base_url)